# Custom fonts working on certain page on but not working on other pages on Mac Safari browser

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, font-face, wordpress-gutenberg

I am working on a website. Website link is: https://chessteacher.org/
I am using custom font "MV Boli" on the website. I generated the font face and added the fonts item inside the child theme. Font is showing on home page but not working on other pages on **"Mac Safari"** browser. Here is the font-face.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MV Boli', sans-serif;
    src: url('https://chessteacher.org/wp-content/themes/kadence-child/fonts/MVBoli.eot');
    src: url('https://chessteacher.org/wp-content/themes/kadence-child/fonts/MVBoli.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('https://chessteacher.org/wp-content/themes/kadence-child/fonts/MVBoli.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('https://chessteacher.org/wp-content/themes/kadence-child/fonts/MVBoli.woff') format('woff'),
        url('https://chessteacher.org/wp-content/themes/kadence-child/fonts/MVBoli.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('https://chessteacher.org/wp-content/themes/kadence-child/fonts/MVBoli.svg#MVBoli') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

I added the above code inside "Customize > Additional CSS". Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your site in **Dev tools netwok tab**, you'll see the Boli is not loaded.

As the "MV Boli" has only one font style (italic) and one font-weight (normal/400) you also need to make sure all text elements use only these styles.

That's important since heading tags like `<h1>` will by default use a bolder font-weight and a normal (non italic) font style.

```
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "MV Boli", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Besides better remove the 2 font-family value in your `@font-face` rule.
A `@font-face` rule is intended to map a font-family name to a specific font file, hence, you don't need a fallback family name like "sans-serif".

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MV Boli';
    src: url('https://chessteacher.org/wp-content/themes/kadence-child/fonts/MVBoli.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/38058/MVBOLI.woff') format('woff'),
        url('https://chessteacher.org/wp-content/themes/kadence-child/fonts/MVBoli.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-display: swap;
}
```